# How to write a safe `length` function to a `Vec` in Agda?

Tags: agda, dependent-type

Since we have `Data.Vec`, we know what `Vec` is.

I want to prove that Nat and `Vec ⊤` are isomorphic.

I've successfully created a function that proves Nat can be converted to Vec:

```
ℕ→vec : (n : ℕ) → Vec ⊤ n
ℕ→vec  zero   = []
ℕ→vec (suc a) = tt ∷ ℕ→vec a
```

While when I'm trying to write a corresponding `vec→ℕ`, I failed.

I want to write something like this (it doesn't compile but it's readable):

```
vec→ℕ : ∀ {n} → Vec ⊤ n → (n : ℕ)
vec→ℕ  []      = zero
vec→ℕ (tt ∷ a) = suc (vec→ℕ a)
```

In the first code, it's ensured that the argument is exactly the length of the return value.
However, how can I ensure that the length of the first argument is exactly the return value?

Comment: Even if you define both of these, you're not going to have an isomorphism. At best, you'll have an embedding since while it should be possible to prove that vec→ℕ (ℕ→vec n) == n for all n, ℕ→vec (vec→ℕ v) is not equal to v for all v.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know, if it is the best solution, but is what I had figured out.

```
open import Data.Vec
open import Data.Unit
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Product

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

vec→ℕ : ∀ {n} → Vec ⊤ n → ∃ (λ m → n ≡ m)
vec→ℕ  []      = zero , refl
vec→ℕ (tt ∷ a) with vec→ℕ a
vec→ℕ (tt ∷ a) | m , refl = suc m , refl
```

Instead of saying that the result is exactly `n`, I've introduced a equality in order that specifies that such function return a `m`, such that `n ≡ m`. Hope that it helps you. Using your type signature, I've got a parse error and developed this.

Comment: Thank you! This is the first time I see how existential type work! Your answer has perfectly solved my problem! :D

Comment: Can't you just pattern match on `{n}` and return `n, refl`, without the case split and the recursion?

Answer (score 7):

You could make `vec→ℕ` definitionally equal to the length:

```
vec→ℕ : ∀ {n} → Vec ⊤ n → ℕ
vec→ℕ {n} _ = n
```

and then I think this is sufficiently transparent to Agda that anywhere you'd need the property that the `ℕ` you get is the right one, it will be available to you automatically (i.e. by reduction).

**Edited to add:** you might think this is underspecified, since `vec→ℕ`'s type doesn't prescribe which exact `ℕ`atural it returns. However, Agda sees through this definition, so e.g. you can prove the following external correctness proof if you need it (but I'd argue it doesn't add any value):

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

vec→ℕ-correct : ∀ {n} {xs : Vec ⊤ n} → vec→ℕ xs ≡ n
vec→ℕ-correct = refl
```

Note that because `vec→ℕ xs` is definitionally equal to `n`, we don't need to look at either `n` or `xs` in the proof.

Comment: This is good! But in this case if you write `vec\r\bN {n} _ = zero` Agda will not give an error. So it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: For the `edit and add`: thanks for your answer! learned a lot about agda :D